# Stopping parameter expansion in write_file content of cloud-init userdata

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cloud-init, terraform

### Background

I'm using Terraform and cloud-init to provision an Ubuntu VM.

The Terraform template contains an embedded cloud-init `user_data` section that contains a `write_file` directive to write a bash script. The hierarchy looks like this:

- Terraform template

  - cloud-init user_data

    - write_content

      - bash script

Inside the bash script, I have the following function

```
mkcd() {
        mkdir -p "${1}"
        cd "${1}"
        }
```

### Problem and question

When the file is written inside the VM, it looks like this:

```
mkcd() {
        mkdir -p "1"
        cd "1"
        }
```

The `${1}` is replaced with just a `1`. The desired behavior is to have the function appear in the written file exactly as it appears in the Terraform template.

**How do I get the function to appear in the written file exactly like this?:**

```
mkcd() {
        mkdir -p "${1}"
        cd "${1}"
        }
```

### Troubleshooting

I have also tried this:

```
mkcd() {
        mkdir -p "$\{1}"
        cd "$\{1}"
        }
```

The file is written exactly as shown, with the backslashes retained.

Comment: It looks like the [Escape Sequence](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings#escape-sequences-1) is `$${1}`

Comment: Check your script for special characters with GNU cat: `cat -A your_script.sh`